# extracting string from URL using regex (on data studio)

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have the following landing page

```
city7900/
cityid=7900
city7900-t40094705.nb1/
```

and I want to merge everything to

```
7900
```

on data studio

I tried using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,'city([^&]+))
```

and it only extract the

```
city7900/
cityid=7900
```

ones
and tried

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,'city([^&]+)|city([^&]+)(.*?)\\-')
```

and it only extracts the `city7900-t40094705.nb1/`

how can I extract all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,'city[^0-9]*([0-9]+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZybOT/1). **Details**:

- `city` - a string
- `[^0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than digits
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits.